# Creating 2 http requests on the same connection

Tags: c#, .net, http

I would like to create 2 HTTP requests on the same connection (HTTP persistent connection).

I'm using HttpWebRequest:

```
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:14890/Service1/3");
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int x = response.GetResponseStream().Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
        string str = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
```

I think if I use `request` again it will create a whole new HTTP connection which I don't want to do.

Is there another class I can use isntead or is there something I'm missing?

I'm also not sure how the WebClient class works with respect to persistent connections.

Comment: Your code will not correctly read the response.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [`KeepAlive` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive.aspx).

For example:

```
string str;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:14890/Service1/3");
request.KeepAlive = true;
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.ASCII)) {
    str = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: And how do I make the second request within that same connection?

Comment: The .Net framework should automatically re-use the connection.

Comment: so the connection is like a static property of HttpWebRequest, I kind of need control of when to have persistent connections and when not to via multiple threads all using different HttpWebRequests.

Comment: It seems like there something missing for control here.  What if I want to maintain 2 HTTP connections.

Comment: @wcf guru needed, no, it's not static. The connection is handled by the ServicePoint class

Comment: @wcf: You need to maintain multiple `ServicePoint` instances.

Comment: ServicePoint is a read only property of the HttpWebRequest though

Comment: @SLaks: Any insight on how to maintain 2 ServicePoints yourself?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep your server session from one httprequest to the next, you have explicitly store and send your session identifier, unlike with msinet.ocx which does it all for you. for instance when connecting to a php webserver, the session identifier is stored in a header labelled Set-Cookie/PHPSESSID=... and this has header has to be manually added to the next httprequest but renamed to Cookie/PHPSESSID=....